# MySQL - Display time, time plus 5 minutes, price

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a table `Aud_Usd` with a Time with minute increments (08-09-2017 10:00:00) and a `Price` (FX conversion rate eg. 0.797). I would like to show in a single table:

```
Time | Price | Time + 5 minutes | Corresponding price to Time + 5 minutes
```

Essentially I would just like to compare how the price has moved in that period. I have been stuck on showing the corresponding price. Currently I have

```
SELECT Time, Price, ADDTIME(Time, '00:01:00') As tplus5, ??
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does this mean? Corresponding price to Time + 5 minutes,

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? That code wont run on both...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT au.Time, au.Price, ADDTIME(au.Time, '00:05:00') As tplus5, 
(select price from Aud_Usd where Time = ADDTIME(au.Time, '00:05:00')) as 
PricePlus5
from Aud_Usd au
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SEC_TO_TIME` to achieve this. So your query will be as follows:

```
SELECT Time, Price, ADDTIME(startTime, SEC_TO_TIME(300)) As tplus5, ....
```